# $N$ people independently picking at least one common number

Tags: combinatorics

From $n$ numbers (e.g. $1,2,...,n$) each member of a group of $N$ people chooses randomly and independently $k$ numbers. What is the probability of the group choosing at least one common number? (for $N=2$ this is straightforward)

Thanks VM

Comment: Hint:  think about calculating the complementary probability, that no number is chosen in common.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the probability that everybody picks $a$ is $(\frac kn)^N$.
More generally, for $r\le k$ numbers $a_1<\ldots <a_r$, the probability of everybody picking these is $\frac{{n-r\choose k-r}^N}{{n\choose k}^N}$.
By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the desired probability is 
$$ n\cdot \frac{{n-1\choose k-1}^N}{{n\choose k}^N}-{n\choose 2}\frac{{n-2\choose k-2}^N}{{n\choose k}^N}+{n\choose 3}\frac{{n-3\choose k-3}^N}{{n\choose k}^N}-{n\choose 4}\frac{{n-4\choose k-4}^N}{{n\choose k}^N}\pm\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks a lot...pardon my ignorance, but I fail to see how you derive the probability term of everybody picking a_1 to a_r.

E.g. N=2, n=5, k=3 -> there are 100 ways two persons can choose 3 numbers out of 5, in 60 of which both choose exactly 2 common numbers (r=2), in 10 of which all 3 numbers are the same (r=3), and in 30 of which they choose exactly 1 common number (r=1), i.e. the probabilities are 0.6, 0.3, and 0.1 respectively...how do these results relate to your formula? Could you elaborate, please?